# Order unique values by frequency

Tags: r, ranking

What function do I need to use to rank first four most popular words in list in R program?

For example,

```
c("apple", "banana", "apple", "banana", "banana", 
  "desk", "pen", "pen", "pen", "pen")
```

to make it like

```
"pen"
"banana"
"apple"
"desk"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

You can sort the tabled values in decreasing order and then take the names to get the output you're looking for.  Try this:

```
> x <- c("apple", "banana", "apple", "banana", "banana", 
         "desk", "pen", "pen", "pen", "pen")
> names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))
## [1] "pen"    "banana" "apple"  "desk"
```

Comment: For slightly less typing, one can switch out `decreasing = TRUE` for `rev`:  `names(rev(sort(table(x))))`

Comment: And one could also write `names(sort(table(x),dec=T))` since R will recognize `dec` as the `decreasing` argument.  A one byte difference between the two. :)

Comment: @Jota if concise is what you are after then you can use `-` instead of `rev()`:  `names(sort(-table(x)))`.

Comment: Also it would be more efficient to reverse just the names instead of the whole table: `rev(names(sort(table(x))))`

Comment: I think it's more efficient to use less functions. `table` and `sort` are costly as-is, and adding `rev` will only slow things down further. `decreasing` is built-in to `sort` so that the user has the option to reverse the operation in the same function.

Answer (score 3):

`table` is intuitive for base R.  Here's a qdap approach:

```
library(qdap)
freq_terms(dat, 4)

##   WORD   FREQ
## 1 pen       4
## 2 banana    3
## 3 apple     2
## 4 desk      1
```

Or...

```
freq_terms(dat, 4)[, 1]
## [1] "pen"    "banana" "apple"  "desk"
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do this would be:

```
k <- {tmp <- table(x); names(tmp)[order(tmp, decreasing = TRUE)]}
k
[1] "pen"    "banana" "apple"  "desk"
```